# Getting wrong latitude longitude returned by geocode api for address

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

While searching for a particular address on google Maps i get the multiple results but the location is correct .However when i try to get the lat/long of the address via geocoding API it returns wrong location lat/long.

This address *"19 West 34 Street PH New York 10001  NY"* is located in *zip code:* 10001, and when searched on google it returns multiple address but the location is correct.

But when searched through google with the *geocoding API* via the URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=19%20West%2034%20Street%20PH+New%20York+NY+10001 it returns wrong results.

Does anybody have any idea regarding the issue?

Comment: Is it just this address or other addresses also?

Comment: I am looping through the database for pinning the addresses on the map, this is the only one which i found, others are showing correct locations.

Comment: What is your code that is making the call?  Or are you just testing with a web browser to the link?

Comment: i'm using php to get the lat long by hitting the url, and getting contents of the page, these values are being stored in the db which i'm later looping through to pin the locations.

Comment: Where is that address supposed to be? What does the "PH" in it represent? Where did that address string come from?  [If I remove the "PH", it seems to return a meaningful result (formatted address is "19 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA")](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=19%20West%2034%20Street+New%20York+NY+10001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"19 West 34 Street PH New York 10001 NY" is not a valid postal address, the "PH" is confusing the geocoder.  If I remove that from the submitted address, I get a single result in the 10001 zipcode:

["19 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001, USA"](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=19%20West%2034%20Street+New%20York+NY+10001)

Another option would be do use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/), that seems to return the correct result with the original string.

Comment: yes, that's the issue , but the problem is that the user is entering the data and on the website search page i'm pinning the locations on the map..

The same address when searched in google maps is resulting in the correct location and not on geocoding map..is this because google map is using places API??

Also i searched for places api but they seem to be use with javascript , is there any way where i can use places api like the geocode pai url , that is i can pass teh address via url to places api instead of geocode api and get the contents of the [age..like i was doing with geocode API